# Vote appropriately to set the lines of our scope

Tags: discussion, scope

As many members of the community were concerned that the scope was too narrow and that many questions were veering towards a particular topic, some members of the community have now started to draw questions that are quite different from what we have been seeing. Many of us have discussed in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22392597#22392597) how the scope should form.

That being said, many users are going to place questions that will test the boundaries of the scope, as well as questions which proved themselves to be slightly controversial in the Area 51 proposal. If you ever disagree with any of them, down vote, vote to close. When you vote to close, please use a custom reason (not a generic reason) so that we can understand the community's thoughts. If you agree, up vote and provide constructive feedback. Save disputes for chat, like always.

Thank you! :D :D :D :D :D